# How do i work with nested model attributes in refinerycms?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes, refinerycms, model-associations

I have seen http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised and tried the same doing with my refinery engine, but i am not able to see the nested fields in my form while adding a record from admin section and also I am not getting any errors.
I am unable to figure out what exactly is happening or may be if i am missing any refinery related configuration thing.

I tried this on Rails Console:

```
 Refinery::Extension::Model.nested_attributes_options
 => {:nested_model_name=>{:allow_destroy=>false, :update_only=>false}}
```

I have 2 models Question and Option, but while submitting form for question with options as nested elements it is giving me Error as below

```
  ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in  Refinery::Papers::Admin::QuestionsController#create
```

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: refinery_papers_options
>
> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"TqL+r60R05+meVhPBXPPipvL+X3ZNx+3dCwoThFBn/Y=", 
>   "question"=>{"content"=>"
>
> aaaaaaaaaa
>
> ",  "correct_answers"=>"a", 
>   "refinery_papers_options"=>{"content"=>"
>
> asdfghjklkmnv
>
> ", 
>   "_destroy"=>"0"},  "position"=>0},  "locale"=>:en}

My Models and view Are:

Question Model:

```
    module Refinery
     module Papers
     class Question < Refinery::Core::BaseModel

      self.table_name = 'refinery_papers_questions'

      attr_accessible :content, :correct_answers, :options_attributes, :position

      validates :content, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

      has_many :options,
        :foreign_key => "refinery_papers_question_id",
        :class_name => "Refinery::Papers::Option",
        :dependent => :destroy

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :options,
        :allow_destroy => true

    end
  end
end 

Option Model:

    module Refinery
       module Papers
         class Option < Refinery::Core::BaseModel

           self.table_name = 'refinery_papers_options'

           attr_accessible :content, :position, :refinery_papers_question_id

           validates :content, :presence => true

           belongs_to :question,
            :class_name => 'Refinery::Papers::Question',
            :foreign_key => :refinery_papers_question_id

          end
        end
      end
```

In views Form for nested fields is like this :

```
<%= f.fields_for :refinery_papers_options do |option_form| %>
   <div class='field'>
     <%= option_form.label :content, "Option" %><br/>
     <%= option_form.text_area :content, :class => "wymeditor widest" %><br/>
    </div>
   <div class='field'>
     <%= option_form.label :_destroy, "Remove Option" -%>
     <%= option_form.check_box :_destroy -%>    
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

When i tried this on rails console i got this stack

> 2.0.0p247 :007 > Refinery::Papers::Question.create({"content"=>"
>
> jhsdacnlkS
>
> ","correct_answers"=>"a",
>   :refinery_papers_options => {"content"=>"
>
> sjdfgczdj
>
> "}})
>   ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign
>   protected attributes: refinery_papers_options     from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/activemodel-3.2.14/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in
>   `process_removed_attributes'  from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/activemodel-3.2.14/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in`
>   debug_protected_attribute_removal'   from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/activemodel-3.2.14/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in
>   `sanitize'    from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/activemodel-3.2.14/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in`
>   sanitize_for_mass_assignment'    from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in
>   `assign_attributes'   from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in`
>   initialize'  from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in
>   `new'     from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in`
>   create'  from (irb):7    from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in
>   `start'   from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in`start'    from
>   /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@refinery/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from script/rails:6:in`require'    from
>   script/rails:6:in `'

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: i dint got any error.It was working as fine and same as it was before but was not ale to see the nested attributes.

Comment: @RajarshiDas hey now i am able to see the fields in views but after submitting the form its giving me mass assignment error for options can help with that.

Comment: sorry for late reply .....if you use rails 4 use [strong_parameter](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) or if rails 3.2 use `attr_accessible :name #all fields` in your model which are assigned by also another solution `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` see the link [whitelist](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/148-protect-mass-assignment)

Comment: @RajarshiDas thanks for reply,i have already done what you are advising, you can check the models code and views code which i have posted above,but instead of that i am getting the mass assignment problem.

Comment: `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` did you try this? check the link i had given

Comment: @RajarshiDas yes i tried that but then also i its giving the same issue.

Comment: @RajarshiDas just to mention that i am using rails 3.2.14

Comment: ahh may be for this `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: refinery_papers_options` what is `refinery_papers_options`

Comment: by the way I did not see it in you `attr_acccessible`

Comment: so your `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false` ? right? or `true` it should be `false` in `application.rb`

Comment: @RajarshiDas thats a name of table for options, but for association i have tried refinery_papers_options_attributes and options_attributtes both as attr_accessible but nothing seems to change.

Comment: actually if you make `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false` it will pass that make sure it is false

Comment: @RajarshiDas i too think that problem is over there only but not able to figure out what exactly it is.

Comment: @RajarshiDas i tried config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false as both false and true too

Comment: not true sir...it should be false then it will never throw this error make false then restart server and prob will definitely solved

Comment: @RajarshiDas i just tried it again as  config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false  but result is same :(

Comment: did you create your application by `rails _3.2.14_ new rickrockstar -m http://refinerycms.com/t/2.1.0` this way

Comment: no i created it this way refinerycms application_name

Comment: please look at the guide http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started

Comment: @RajarshiDas: Does that makes difference?

Comment: @ahmadhamza should be as it was working fine in my application no mass assignment error

Comment: @RajarshiDas Actually the error resolved. Because we didnt build the nested form in the controller. Thats why it is giving us the error.

Answer (score 0):

May be this [link](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/master/pages/app/models/refinery/page.rb) can help.

```
 has_many :parts,
         :foreign_key => :refinery_page_id,
         :class_name => '::Refinery::PagePart',
         :order => 'position ASC',
         :inverse_of => :page,
         :dependent => :destroy,
         :include => ((:translations) if ::Refinery::PagePart.respond_to?(:translation_class))

accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts, :allow_destroy => true
```

There may be confusion regarding the `class names` of different models you have created in the engine. This above code is just a piece of example how the `refinery core` team have done the `nested attributes concept`.